# .cs file is not compiling/changes to code not showing up

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I am coding in C# and have taken over a project in which I have no experience. I am using Visual Studio 2010.

In trying to check that my changes are showing up at all, I changed the existing code:

```
catch (Exception exp)
                {
                    logEvent("Exception (Input File Error) - " + exp.Message);
                }
```

To the following:

```
catch (Exception exp)
                {
                    logEvent("EXAMPLE MESSAGE - " + exp.Message);
                }
```

However the event log doesn't reflect these changes, it still displays the old log event message.

The file I'm trying to make changes to looks like this:
[image]

I have tried the following:

1) Checked the "Properties" has the "Build Action" set to "Compile".

2) Tried deleting the "bin" and "obj" files before cleaning and rebuilding my solution.

3) Double checked the class that is calling the code is correct.

4) Checked the configuration manager to ensure the project containing the .cs file has a "Configuration" of "Debug" and that the "Build" checkbox is selected.

I've hit a bit of a brick wall here, any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: are you sure that particular code is executing and the exception is being thrown?  have you put in a breakpoint and run it through the debugger?

Comment: The code is executing else the program wouldn't run at all, I have added a few breakpoints and it doesn't appear that any of them get hit.

Comment: if the breakpoints aren't getting hit, the code is not executing.

Comment: It wouldn't be an NT Service of some kind?...in which case you would need to stop any running one, make sure the one you've just compiled is installed/updated, and then when it's running ("Started") you "attach" to it, so you can debug/set breakpoints. NT Services are runnable like normal apps...they are managed by the SCM (Service Control Manager).

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7a50syb3(v=vs.110).aspx